# Problemas con 000webhost

Tags: laravel-5, firefox

Veran, ya hice mi proyecto de laravel, denominado Fichero de Juegos Andalucia y lo he subido a un servidor de 000webhost.
El problema es que me esta dando varios problemas de seguridad, probablemente debido a que use un servidor gratuito.
Basicamente, me salta la seguridad del navegador diciendo que es un sitio engañoso y no me permiten entrar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo curioso es que solo me pasa en firefox. Internet Explorer, Google Chrome y incluso Opera permiten que entre sin problemas (y lo reconozco, tal como aparece en la captura de pantalla).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado usar un dominio personalizado, pero el problema se agrava.
¿Que puedo probar?
Para que podais hacer pruebas, aqui teneis mi página: `http://ficherodejuegos.000webhostapp.com`